# Table renderer where there are 2 if statements

Tags: java, jtable, renderer

I have a table renderer that makes a row in my table red depending on the contents of column 11. This works fine and the code is below:

```
tableR = new JTable(modelR)
{
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);


Font myFont = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,10);
Font myFont1 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,10);
int rowModelId = convertRowIndexToModel( row );


if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
                    if (tableR.getColumnCount() >= 0) {
                   String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(rowModelId, 11);
                        c.setBackground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
                        c.setForeground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK);
                        c.setFont("0.0".equals(type) ? myFont1: myFont);

                    }

 }  

 return c;

}
```

I now want to additionally implement the same thing with column 12, so that if a criteria is met, in this case "u" that particular row is yellow. My attempt is below however now no colour appears at all in the table. In addition to this what will happen if column 11, and column 12 are coloured --what would happen in this scenario?

Here is my attempted go:

```
tableR = new JTable(modelR)
{
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);


Font myFont = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,10);
Font myFont1 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,10);
int rowModelId = convertRowIndexToModel( row );
int rowModelId1 = convertRowIndexToModel( row );

if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
                    if (tableR.getColumnCount() >= 0) {
                              String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(rowModelId, 11);
                        c.setBackground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
                        c.setForeground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK);
                        c.setFont("0.0".equals(type) ? myFont1: myFont);

                    }
                         if (tableR.getColumnCount() >= 0) {
                              String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(rowModelId1, 12);
                        c.setBackground("u".equals(type) ? Color.YELLOW : Color.WHITE);
                        c.setForeground("u".equals(type) ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK);
                        c.setFont("u".equals(type) ? myFont1: myFont);

                    }


 }  


 return c;

}
```

Comment: Why on the first code example you have c and d, while at the second one you have only c? also, rowModelId and rowModelId1 will have the same value making c change the same row.

Comment: @ Infested i have deleted that out now, it was part of my experimentation to try to get it to work thinking that if i create another prepare renderer named d and then return both c and d i would get both renderers back. I have deleted it from the question now thanks for pointing that out

Comment: how do you want the columns to be painted? when a row is selected or when a column is selected? or do you want to paint the columns not selected or something else?

Comment: @infested the so in the first if statement if column 11 contains a "0.0" then the row is painted red, and the next if statement if column 12 contains "u" then i want the row to be painted yellow, at the moment since i have introduced my attempt of 2 if statements nothing is painted

Comment: alright, if the 12th column doesnt contain u, but the 11th does contain 0.0 - what paint should it have?

Comment: @ infested so in this case the row where the 12th column DOESNT have a "u" then this row would be standard row (no colour just black font and white background) and if the 11th column DOES have a 0.0 then the row would have a background of red and a white font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tableR = new JTable(modelR) {
    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        Font myFont = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,10);
        Font myFont1 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,10);
        int rowModelId = convertRowIndexToModel( row );
        int rowModelId1 = convertRowIndexToModel( row );
    if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
        if (tableR.getColumnCount() >= 0) {
            String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(rowModelId1, 12);
            if("u".equals(type)) {
                c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                c.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                c.setFont(myFont1);
                return c;
            }
            type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(rowModelId, 11);
            if("0.0".equals(type)) {
                c.setBackground(Color.RED);
                c.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                c.setFont(myFont1);
                return c;
            }
        }
        c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        c.setFont(myFont);
    }
    return c;
}
}
```

here you go, i hope this solves it

Answer (score 1):

Based on your somewhat weirdo code snippet I've created the following. Can't say I understand why you would base color on both column 11 & 12 values...

Note:

- Used `JTable.getValueAt` instead of using `TableModel.getValueAt`
- Used `JTable.convertColumnIndexToView` since I suppose by column 11 & 12 you mean those from the model, not the view (view & model index will change when moving around columns in the view)

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class example {
    static Font myFont = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,10);
    static Font myFont1 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,10);
    private static Component createTable() {
        Object rowData[][] = new Object[][]{
            {"0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0"},
            {"b","6.70","q","l","b","6.70","q","l","b","6.70","q","l","p"},
            {"0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0"},
            {"u","u","u","u","u","u","u","u","u","u","u","u","u"},
            {"b","6.70","q","l","b","6.70","q","l","b","6.70","q","l","p"},
            {"u","u","u","u","u","u","u","u","u","u","u","u","u"},          
        };
        Object colData[] = {"Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5","Col6","Col7","Col8","Col9","Col10","Col11","Col12","Col13"};
        return new JTable( rowData, colData ) {
            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                if (isRowSelected(row) || getColumnCount()==0) 
                    return c;

                String type = (String) getValueAt(row, convertColumnIndexToView( 11 ));
                if("0.0".equals(type))
                {
                    c.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    c.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    c.setFont(myFont1);
                    return c;
                }               
                type = (String) getValueAt( row, convertColumnIndexToView( 12 ) );
                if("u".equals(type))
                {
                    c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    c.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    c.setFont(myFont1);
                    return c;
                }
                c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                c.setFont(myFont);
                return c;
            }
        };
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                f.add(new JScrollPane(createTable()), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                f.setSize(500, 500);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: you have a bug there, if the 12th column has u then you should paint the row with yellow, but if the 11th column has 0.0 you paint it red and just return

Comment: @Infested OP wasn't really clear on that matter... *"[...]the same thing with column 12, so that if a criteria is met, in this case "u" that particular row is yellow"*. That follows his first criterium. If he wants the 12 check to go first, he can surely reorder the checks =)